# Adding HTML to a Woocomerce product page

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

We create 360 degree views for products. And I want to integrate them to our Woocomerce test Products. But I can't add HTML to the product site via elementor so I need some help and I'm not really into web development.

This is the product page: https://www.schnappzu.net/produkt/samsung-smart-watch/ ‎and I want to add the following HTML code.

The best way would be to replace the Product image with this 360 degree animation, if this is not possible, the HTML code should be shown below the product image.

Code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.fisher-softmedia.de/live/schnappzu/beispiel/template/css/euroviewer_styles_native.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <script src="https://www.fisher-softmedia.de/live/schnappzu/beispiel/3d_artikel/Smartwatch/viewerconf.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://www.fisher-softmedia.de/live/schnappzu/beispiel/template/js/init.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script>init("Smartwatch", 0, 0)</script>
<script src="https://www.fisher-softmedia.de/live/schnappzu/beispiel/template/js/viewer-html.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://www.fisher-softmedia.de/live/schnappzu/beispiel/template/js/euroviewer_core.1721.production.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: This is possible but requires some development. You'll need to create a woocommerce child theme and change the html within the woocommerce/content-single-product.php page. Here's a link for Woocommerce theming  - https://docs.woocommerce.com/documentation/plugins/woocommerce/woocommerce-codex/theming/

Comment: So if manage It to edit the theme and add an section or div I don't know to input the custom links for the Products. Is there maybe a snippet to add this function to the backend? I also don't know how to code php or javascript.

Comment: In order to make these changes, you're going to need an understanding of html, php & jquery. Also how to implement the jquery plugin which allows you to demo the 360 animation. If you don't have this knowledge it's probably achievable but will likely take you some time.